# Two unique key in one table SQL

Tags: sql, db2

I have two unique key in one table and I want to write a query that connects me to two unique key and displays them in one record. Currently, the query returns 2 records to me where unique key = ID in the first and unique key = PM in the second record. And I would like to have one record unique key = ID, PM

```
i.COLNAMES  AS CCOLUMNS, C.TABNAME
FROM syscat.columns C
JOIN SYSCAT.INDEXES I ON I.TABNAME = C.TABNAME
WHERE UNIQUERULE IN ('P','U')
```

Comment: there cannot be two primary keys within a table. At least one of them might be unique key I suppose.

Comment: ... or one primary key, but **composite**.

Comment: sorry unique key

Comment: What if a table has more than two unique keys? (which can happen...)

Comment: What is `ID` in the `unique key = ID`? Column name? Index name? What output do you want to have exactly, if you have 2 unique indexes: idx1 (col1, col2), idx2 (col1, col3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
SELECT tabname, LISTAGG('Indexname:' || indname || ' ' || COLNAMES, ', ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY indname)
  FROM SYSCAT.INDEXES
 WHERE UNIQUERULE IN ('P','U')
 GROUP BY TABNAME
```